# How to replace a piece of text in Emacs with a link or reference?

Tags: emacs

When writing emails with Emacs, I like to use this format with numbers between square brackets to point to URLs.

Example:

> The first version [1] is still buggy, so I have downloaded SomeAlternative [2] instead.
>
> [1]: http://blahblahblahblah.com/version1
>
> [2]: http://gaaaaaaaah.com/

Is there any Emacs mode or key sequence that allows me to quickly replace a URL with a reference in this format ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the genuine `footnote-mode` minor mode.

Answer (score 2):

org-mode footnote will do this.